# Do we know the genome contains all the information necessary for embryonic development?

Tags: dna, development, genomes, information

Since high school biology I've assumed that all information necessary for creating an organism is found in its genome.  As [Nature's Scitable site](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/introduction-what-is-dna-6579978/) says:

> Deoxyribonucleic acid, more commonly known as DNA, is a complex molecule that contains all of the information necessary to build and maintain an organism.

However, I've been reading Sean Carroll's "Endless Forms Most Beautiful" and here is one passage that illustrates the question in the title.

> Ultimately, the beginning of spatial information in the embryo often traces back to asymmetrically distributed molecules deposited in the egg during its production in the ovary that initiate the formation of the two main axes of the embryo (so the egg did come before the chicken).

Dr. Carroll seems to be saying that the information determining whether genetic switches are on or off ultimately does not come from the embryo's genome, but rather comes from other molecules provided by the mother.  So, my question is whether we know these molecules responsible for initializing the switches that regulate gene expression can be traced back to something in the mother's genome?  If we don't know these molecules trace back to the mother's genome, then is there some other reason we think the genome "contains all of the information necessary to build and maintain an organism"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136358/discussion-on-question-by-yters-how-do-we-know-dna-contains-all-the-information).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second quote is about stochastically determining which side is the "head" and which is the "tail", effectively, which occurs by positive feedback of an existing gradient. This is not really a matter of information *stored* in the sense that we think of information stored in DNA bases or bits on magnetic tape, the passage seems to be referring to information in the sense of a [reduction in uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty) about the state of the universe. The way a developing embryo chooses where the head is going to be is like dumping a bag of M&Ms on the table and having the head develop wherever the highest concentration of yellow M&Ms are. If you expect them to be uniformly distributed, you'd be correct statistically, but for any one iteration there will be a non-uniformity that determines what happens next: that's information, reduction in statistical uncertainty. If you, via the power of a thought experiment cousin of [Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon), were to scramble the positions of molecules in the egg cell, that would change where the "head" develops.

Yet, all of this is guided by proteins that are created and function according to the "instructions" in DNA. DNA doesn't have information about where in the future there will randomly be a concentration of yellow M&Ms, but it does have the information to synthesize proteins that react to concentrations of yellow M&Ms, causing a positive feedback loop that further concentrates them on a particular axis.

For embryonic development, these yellow M&Ms are mRNA transcripts, and at least in drosophila, these initial transcripts are indeed made in the egg cell, not post-fertilization (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drosophila_embryogenesis#Anterior-posterior_axis_patterning_in_Drosophila). It's possible to introduce a mutation to a fly that will only affect her offspring, by interfering with transcription of these mRNAs. More generally, [maternal effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_effect) are observed when the egg cell or developing environment has some influence on the offspring.

However, all those influences are coded in the DNA of the next generation, too, so it also seems reasonable to say that the genome contains all the information necessary. Containing all needed information to do X is not the same as being able to do X. To turn DNA into RNA transcripts, and to turn transcripts into proteins, requires more than information, it requires machinery. We can say the information to build those machines is [also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_polymerase_II) [in the DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosomal_RNA).

Honorable mention to [mitochondrial DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA), which comes entirely from the egg cell.

Generally, I think learning about biology from these grand pronouncements like "all information is in DNA" is a bad way to learn biology. Biology is not mathematics, we do not operate in the certainty of proof. Learn how things actually work, first, rather than trying to prove or disprove "truths". These statements are meant to capture wonder and convey the basic order of things, they are not dogma (even if someone [regretfully calls it that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_dogma_of_molecular_biology)).

Comment: Nice answer! Reminds me of the last line of Gunga Din. Mitochondrial DNA does deserve an honorable mention. :)

Comment: Also, and feel free to delete this, but I always thought of Watson as something of an imposter, a feeling that solidified on listening to him speak a few times at Cold Spring Harbor, and we’re chiseled in stone with his racist views.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, and your answer does illustrate why scientists tend to think all the information is ultimately stored in the DNA.  From what you say, the asymmetric concentration appears to be as informative as a coin flip.  The head formation has to start somewhere, and there has to be a concentration to get things started, but the concentration's placement is randomly distributed, so there is no specific instruction identifying a particular location where the head has to form.  I'm acquiring some books on epigenetics to see if all developmental instructions are indeed encoded in DNA.

Comment: I also just found this question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30645/do-changes-in-an-organisms-cell-modify-the-genetic-information-it-uses-for-repr?rq=1, which says mutations in the gametes are heritable.  Which would be one example of heritable information that is not encoded in the DNA.  I can ask a separate question about this to see if it falsifies the statement that "all information is in the DNA".

Comment: @yters Though "epigentic" is quite broad, most of what is described as epigenetics still involves DNA, it's just outside the traditional ACGT bases. I do not understand why you think heritable mutations in gametes would not involve DNA. I don't think "all information is in the DNA" is a statement you should bother falsifying, rather, you should think about and understand what someone meant to convey by making that statement.

Comment: @BryanKrause there is a subtle distinction in my question that I'm having trouble getting across.  It can be both true that the mechanisms of transmitting epigenetic information is encoded in DNA, i.e. proteins, while the information itself may not track back to specific instructions encoded in the DNA.  I'm having trouble asking my question in the right way to get the answer.  Think of this analogy.  When I type a Word document, the document is dependent on the Word source code that generates the Word program.  However, the information in the document cannot be traced back to the source code.

Comment: @yters Part of the problem might be that you are not expressing a question of interest to biology. Most biologists only really care to understand how the biology works - there's enough stuff going on there to spend many lifetimes on figuring it out and it isn't necessary to apply it to some greater truth for it to be interesting.

Comment: It might be worth thinking about a plant...many plants are of indeterminate size. They grow according to their environment. The instructions for that growth are all encoded in their DNA, but there is a lot of external "information" that will determine the plant's final morphology. For example, if it's receiving a lot of shade early on, some plants will attempt to grow very tall very quickly to escape the shade, at the expense of growing wider. That's "information" in the universe uncertainty/entropy sense; it's not information in the sense of the first quote in your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136641/discussion-between-yters-and-bryan-krause).

Comment: In your Word document example, all of the environmental conditions: sunlight, soil contents, neighboring plants and any signals they release, damage from predators, these are all like the keys you strike while you have Word open, but the way that those inputs are rendered into the plant shape you see today is all in Word's source code, and to generate another plant that follows the same rules given the same external input, all you have to do is copy the Word source code.

Comment: @BryanKrause - so many attempts to teach/answer. Hence why you’re a better [person] than I am, Gunga Din.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, concerning the theory of epigenetics and the concept of epigenetic modification of 'gene expression' -- or of the data encoded in DNA in the form of its base sequence and structural conformation --, it is important to realise that all the enzymes implicated in such epigenetic processes must themselves be encoded in DNA and produced through the mechanisms of transcription and translation, all of the enzymes and proteins associated with which processes, transcription factors and so on, and including histones themselves, must also be thus encoded.

Putting aside such contention about what is inevitably the self-controlling function of DNA transcription however, the conception of a genome constituted primarily by the DNA molecules comprising cell nuclear chromatin is a theoretical construct permitting a broad understanding and its more-or-less consistent experimental verification of the phenomena of heredity and of the relation between the old-fashioned ideas of the phenotype and genotype.

The derivative notion that DNA contains all the information necessary for the growth of organisms is only the imputation of the prevailing paradigm of causality to that relation: thus that the form of DNA 'causes' the intricacies of growth to occur -- and this is no doubt useful in an empirical context, particularly one in which the genome embodied in or by DNA is to be manipulated towards some end.

However, it might be helpful at times to consider the scenario from a different philosophical perspective, to put the horse before the cart as it were, and to imagine that the dynamic and evolving structure of DNA is rather a reflection, at what we define as the cellular level, of the singular process of life, growth and attendant evolutionary transition -- correspondingly understood as an orderly process -- conceived in its more essential sense, than its cause; therefore to view DNA as a theoretical instrument for describing fairly precisely and in an analytically consistent way in physico-chemical terms this singular process, notwithstanding significant gaps in the capacity for that theory generally to account for the entirety of that instrument: for example, to account for the function of non-coding DNA (which must inevitably require a revision and expansion of the philosophical perspective itself).

Clearly there is far more to this process of life and evolutionary growth than can be accounted for by the view of DNA as it currently stands in orthodox cellular biology, even if it is also true that there is no conceivable aspect of that process which will not be reflected -- which will not have its manifestation -- at some level, however subtle, of that dynamic structure and conformation of DNA.

Comment: It’s nice that you gave an answer, but one of the top expectations on this site is that answers are supported by reliable sources. Please provide some support for your answer(even though it’s good, helpful, and a perspective as opposed to an actual answer.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse  The intention was only to proffer a reasoned response to a question which cannot really be answered in the ordinary sense, not the least because the terms are ill-defined -- 'information', 'build an organism'. Eventually, the only way to address confusion about the relation between the chemical structure of the genome and the phenomenon of living organisms, of dynamic life itself, is to adopt a view capable of putting the theoretical construct of DNA as the basis of the genome in its proper philosophical perspective. The logic of a perspective must be able to support itself.

Comment: I am only informing you about site culture, which is meant to be helpful. You have no upvotes; I hope that changes. This type of answer may be perfect on a different site. That says something about the site and about the answer. It doesn’t answer the question, that’s all. On this site, answers must do that.

Comment: The main remit of the Stack Exchange network is to exist as a repository of knowledge and solutions to problems. Whilst a fresh perspective on the underlying philosophy of an approach can be healthy and sometimes very necessary, it's not what we do here.

Comment: As you wish. The question had remained unanswered for 5 days, which should tell you something about the sort of response required -- which is one that attempts to reframe it in terms more likely to address the philosophical confusion implicit in that question itself. Perhaps I should have been more succinct: 'We' do not KNOW that DNA, considered as a 'molecule', contains ALL the 'information' etc., nor CAN we know that. At the same time, we do not NEED to know that in any meaningful empirical context. Also, the first paragraph of the answer DOES address the contention about epigenetics.

Comment: Your reasoning is appreciated, as is your willingness to help the OP. *On this site*, the answer is not philosophical, it’s empirical. It’s also(to me) just too broad and the OP too argumentative to bother answering the question.

Comment: Here's an example of missing information.  When scientists inserted the fly's eyeless gene into a mouse, it created mouse eye cells, not fly eye cells.  So, the gene had enough information to signal "create eye cells", but did not have the information to specify the kind of eye cell.  In the context of my question, this is an example where the eyeless gene has insufficient information to create an eye.

Comment: @yters It's also an example of the limitations of the term 'information' in such contexts; as pointed out in the answer you cite, this sort of example clearly illustrates the experimental impossibility of validating your argument in the way you suggest, which is not to say that the idea itself that there is more to the elaboration of living organisms than the physicochemical form of DNA construed as the substrate of the genome is incorrect.Consider the case in which sensory 'information' is conveyed to mechanisms of epigenetic modification of 'gene ' expression. While the origin of this data..

Comment: ...while the origin of this data is exterior to the cell and even the body, it becomes 'information' relevant to the organism only within it; moreover, all the pathways of this transmission and transition of such data to epigenetic function -- including the constituents of sensory organs themselves: cilia in the nose, tension of the stapedius muscle and so on -- directly implicate enzymes and peptides, including transcription factors etc, whose production is eventually encoded as some form of 'information' within the cell, primarily in the structure of DNA, but also importantly within...

Comment: ...within the whole cellular and cell nuclear context of that DNA, conceived in its dynamic entirety; meaning that this inevitably includes such information as the relation between chromosomes, and between DNA constituents of cell nuclei and of mitochondria, in cells adjacent and distant, considered at a quantum mechanical level

Comment: ...considered at a quantum mechanical level. A real can of conceptual worms, especially in the empirical terms of attempting to relate specific pieces of DNA explicitly to crude phenotypical features. It is however a subject worthy of deeper contemplation than is likely pertinent to experimental scenarios; which is what ordinarily leads to some expansion or revision of 'philosophical perspective'. Good luck with that; it can get pretty scary sometimes.

Comment: What I don't understanding is why the term "information" is considered confusing in this discussion.  Information, in my programming mind, is the bits encoding instructions on how to bring about a certain result.  Take Windows, for example.  The code for Windows contains all the instructions necessary to instantiate the operating system within a particular hardware context.  However, the code does not contain all the instructions necessary to create the hardware context.  Likewise with an organism's genome...

Comment: Likewise with an organism's genome, the question is whether it is the same sort of situation.  Obviously, within the context of a cell and the womb, the genome has enough information to instantiate a particular creature.  But, is the information sufficient to create the cell and womb?  Let's imagine we have the perfect scientist, with skill and knowledge way beyond current human limits.  Can this scientist, with full knowledge of biochemistry, look at a genome and use the instructions encoded there to make the creature, womb and all?  If not, then there is further information...

Comment: If not, then there is further information necessary for the generation of the creature that is encoded elsewhere than the genome.  This has practical implications.  My prior naive understanding of genetics was that all DNA was in a sense "interchangeable".  Every genome contained a complete set of instructions to generate a creature.  Which also means that different instruction sets could be mixed and matched (at least by our perfect scientist) and generate new creatures....

Comment: and generate new creatures.  For example, our perfect scientist could graft in the wing instruction set from a bat into the genome of a walrus, and with suitable adjustments to the genome code taking into account the new environment, could produce a flying bat walrus.  On the other hand, if the genomic information is incomplete, and epigenetic information is also necessary for creation of the bat wing, then no matter what DNA from the bat genome is spliced into the walrus genome, our scientist will never be able to attach bat wings to a walrus....

Comment: bat wings to a walrus.  In a more practical context, human characteristics may not be fully reducible to the genome, and so no matter how much knowledge we gain about manipulation of the genome, we may never be able to, say, give everyone a perfect IQ, exquisite physical beauty, nor extremely long life.  Such human traits may be hereditary, but not encoded in the genome, but encoded in some other fashion...

Comment: encoded in some other fashion. That bioengineering human perfection is possible through manipulation of the genome I believe is a huge assumption of the modern biotechnology enterprise, one which no one appears to apply much of a critical eye.  Going back to my question, this sense of information as the instruction set which gives full control over all aspects of a creature seems plain to me, and I'm curious why we are confident this complete instruction set is contained within the genome.

Comment: @jeremiah I've rewritten my question with a specific example.  Hopefully this is clearer what I am asking.

Comment: @yters Quite right: more generally, sensory 'information' is modifying the existence of an organism at all times through what amount to 'epigenetic' means. However, in order to respond to this 'nurture' side of things. the state of the organism must already be open -- primed -- to respond to it; it must be able to 'hear' the data as it were, and this is the function of the dynamic condition of the DNA/genome at any moment. You must ask yourself WHY you are asking this sort of question and the answer to that is philosophical: thus the form of my answer, which as is evident is not welcome here.

Comment: All philosophical inquiry, into truth, eventually reduces to a single question: is all of this beautiful intricate reality accidental, or is it ordered? Here it is critical to concede that if universal reality is ONE INDIVISIBLE UNITY, one 'quantum field', one 'substance' etc., then it must be one or the other, totally and entirely accidental, OR totally and entirely ordered by a singular universal CAUSE. Real understanding, wisdom, flows only from the latter if the assumption of universal unity is accepted as self-evidently true. The prevailing paradigm in the sciences is based on the former.

Comment: @jeremiah I'm asking because what I was taught about DNA does not seem to be correct based on what I now know about science.  Yes, there may be some sort of teleological cause behind it all, which does seem the much more plausible explanation.  I have a lot of experience programming, and my MSc was in evolutionary algorithms, and evolutionary algorithms cannot produce anything like the intricately arranged structures we see in animals, nor the sort of code that programmers can write!